# If $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ satisfies lying over, then $\textrm{ht } IS \leq \textrm{ht } I$.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ be a homomorphism of Noetherian rings with prime spectra $X, Y$, and suppose the contraction map $\phi^{\ast}: Y \rightarrow X$ is surjective.  I'm trying to show that for any ideal $I$ of $R$, the height of $IS$ (that is, $\phi(I)S$) is $\leq$ the height of $I$.

It's obvious in the special case that $\phi$ satisfies *incomparability*: that is, if $Q_1 \subset Q_2$ are primes of $S$, then $\phi^{-1} Q_1 \subset \phi^{-1} Q_2$ (proper inclusion).  It follows from here that if $Q$ is a prime of $S$, then $$\textrm{ht } Q \leq \textrm{ht } \phi^{-1}Q$$  So, choose a minimal prime ideal $P$ of $I$ whose height is that of $I$, let $Q$ be a prime of $S$ contracting to $P$.  Then $IS \subseteq Q$, so $$\textrm{ht } IS \leq \textrm{ht } Q \leq \textrm{ht } \phi^{-1}Q  = \textrm{ht } I $$

$\blacksquare$

If you don't have incomparability, you can have $\textrm{ht } Q > \textrm{ht } \phi^{-1}Q$, even if lying over holds.  For example, let $A$ be a ring of dimension $> 1$ containing a field $k$.  Then the contraction of any height one prime of $A$ under the inclusion map $k \rightarrow A$ has height zero.

Let $J$ be the kernel of $\phi$.  I had thought to split $\phi$ up as a surjection $R \rightarrow R/J$ followed by an injection $\overline{\phi}: R/J \rightarrow S$.  Now the injection $\overline{\phi}$ inherits the lying over property, and extension of ideals is transitive.  So it suffices to consider the cases where $\phi$ is surjective and injective separately.

In the surjective case, the contraction map satisfies incomparability, so we can apply the argument I mentioned.  Now I'm left with proving the result when $\phi$ is injective and I haven't gotten too far.  I thought Krull's altitude theorem might come in somewhere, since the minimal number of generators of $IS$ is $\leq$ the minimal number of generators of $I$.

I would appreciate a small hint (please don't give me the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $R\subset S$ be an extension of noetherian rings satisfying LO, and $\mathfrak a\subsetneq R$ an ideal. Then $\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak aS\le\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak a$.

- It's enough to prove this for prime ideals.
- One may assume $R$ local.
- Use systems of parameters and [Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem).

Comment: LO is basically used to ensure us that the extensions of ideals we are working with are proper.

Comment: Can you provide a formal proof of what you stated?